# Verifying Solution of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose that w(x,t; τ) is the solution of the following initial value problem of the
wave equation:

$w_{tt} −c^2 w_{xx} = 0, −∞< x < +∞,  t > τ $

$w = 0$ and $w_t = f(x,τ), $ when $t = τ$.

Show that $u(x,t) = \int_0 ^t w(x,t,τ) dτ$ is the solution of the initial value problem of the inhomogeneous wave equation

$u_{tt} −c^2 u_{xx} = f(x,t), −∞< x < +∞, t > 0 $

$u(x,0) = 0, u_t(x,0) = 0$

I computed $u_t , u_{tt}, u_x, u_{xx}$ (by making use of the Leibniz Rule) as follows:

$u_t = w(x,t,t) + \int_0 ^t w_t (x,t,τ) dτ$
$u_{tt} = 2w_t(x,t,t) +\int_0 ^t w_{tt} (x,t,τ)dτ$
$u_x = \int_0 ^t w_x(x,t,τ)dτ $
$u_{xx}=\int_0 ^t w_{xx}(x,t,τ)dτ  $

but this gives $u_t (x,0) = w(x,0)$ which I'm not sure should be zero. I also couldn't show $u_{tt}-c^2 u_{xx} = f(x,t)$ and the usage of $\tau$ only made me more confused... maybe I'm not computing the derivatives correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your derivatives are wrong. You need to use the Leibniz rule when taking time derivatives of integrals. Example: $\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t f(t;\tau)d\tau = f(t;\tau) + \int_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t;\tau)d\tau$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @kevinkayaks thanks for the pointer. I've given it a retry and edited my derivatives. I wonder if it's correct? I'm still doubtful about $u_t (x,0)= w(x,0;\tau)$ and how it could equal zero? I think only$w(x, t=\tau;\tau)=0$?

Comment: According to the Leibniz rule, you evaluate the prior integration variable (in your case $\tau$) at the bound (in your case $t$): $$u_t = w (x, t; \color{red} t) + \int_0^t w_t (x,t ; \tau) \mathrm d \tau.$$
You are sure that $u(x,t)$ is really defined as given by you, and not as $$u(x, t) = \int_0^t w(x, \tau) \mathrm d \tau?$$

Comment: Good point @Dan. The example I wrote above is wrong.

Comment: @DanDoe I noticed that instead of $w(x,t;\tau)$ in the integral, it is $w(x,t,\tau)$, does that make any difference? I just though of it as a notation but that's really how u is defined in the question

Comment: And you are also sure that it is not $$\color{red} 2 w_t = f(x, \tau) ?$$
That would then at least solve the PDE (if you somehow "reduce" $w(x, t, \tau)$ to $w(x, \tau)$ for the case $t = \tau$.

Comment: @DanDoe it isn't. I was also confused because I got an extra factor of 2 at the end while trying to verify the solution

Comment: @Meow typically the semicolon notation indicates the initial condition. $w(x,t;\tau)$ says the value of $w$ at $x,t$ given that the initial conditions were set at $\tau < t$, or something of the like.

Comment: @kevinkayaks thanks for the clarification of the notation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$u(x,t) = \int_0^t w(x,t;\tau)d\tau.$$
We have that $w(x,t;t)=0$ and $w_t(x,t;t)=f(x,t).$ (A note - don't get confused by the dummy variables).
The first time derivative is therefore
$$u_t(x,t) = w(x,t;t) + \int_0^t w_t(x,t;\tau)d\tau,$$
which simplifies to
$$u_t(x,t) = \int_0^t w_t(x,t;\tau)d\tau.$$
The second is then
$$u_{tt}(x,t) = w_t(x,t,t) + \int_0^t w_{tt}(x,t;\tau)d\tau$$
which simplifies to
$$u_{tt}(x,t) = f(x,t) + \int_0^t w_{tt}(x,t;\tau)d\tau.$$
Plugging these into the original PDE therefore gives
$$f(x,t) + \int_0^t \Big[w_{tt}(x,t;\tau)-c^2w_{xx}(x,t;\tau)\Big]d\tau = f(x,t),$$
which works out to $0=0$.

Notice this depends on @Dan's correct application of Leibnitz's rule.

Comment: Thanks! This really makes a lot of sense. Big thanks to Dan too for demonstrating the correct method of using integrating using Leibnitz's rule. :))

Comment: I didnt get it right that the question actually states that if $$t = \tau \Rightarrow w(x, t, \tau = t) = 0.$$ Too early and not enough coffee I guess... But nice that we managed to sort it out :)